# nginx rewrite browser address have an abnormal url splicing occurred

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I want to implement the following with nginx：

https://www.example.com/project1 --> /data/www/pro1/public

https://www.example.com/project2 --> /data/www/pro2/public

Here is my nginx configuration：

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    index index.html index.php;
    root html;

    rewrite_log on;

    error_log /data/wwwlogs/itjuzi/xxxerror.log debug;

    access_log  /data/wwwlogs/itjuzi/saas.itjuzi.com.log  access;

    location /project1 {
        alias /data/www/pro1/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @pro1;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            }
    }

    location @pro1 {
        rewrite /project1/(.*)$ /project1/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```

This correctly accesses the index.php of the pro1 project.

But the browser address is strange:

[https://www.example.com/https:/www.example.com/project1/login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxxQI.png)

This problem has been bothering me all day.

HELP ME! !!
THANKS ^_^

Comment: This redirect most likely came from your PHP code. You should look there instead.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, you are right. the problem comes from the code of the PHP website. fix PHP routing. thank you for your help.